# Aria labelledby is not valid - 508 compliance

Tags: accessibility

I'm receiving this error from the 508 compliance

`The 'id' "authorizationsFiltersMember" specified for the WAI-ARIA property 'aria-labelledby' value is not valid`

I've tried with `authorizations filters member` `authorizations_filters_member` and none of these works ?

How should I call it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

All it is telling you is that you have either:

- self referenced (i.e. `<p id="authorizationsFiltersMember" aria-labelledby="authorizationsFiltersMember">`) for example. Something can't be labelled by itself.
- or that you have a typo in the element you are referencing (or you don't have an element with that ID at all).
- or that the element you are referencing cannot be used as a label (i.e. if you gave it or it has a `role` that is an interactive element etc.)

Most likely is that you have a typo in the ID so try copy and pasting it again (ensure there are no spaces before and after it), it is a perfectly valid ID in terms of length and format.

As a side note: "authorizations filters member" would actually try and reference 3 elements with the IDs "authorizations", "filters" and "member" and combine them in that order to create the label for the element.

Comment: Thanks Graham !! Based on your comments seems to be the second one ? I'm not sure. Because the element doesn't have an id at all ? . I've updated on my post the input that is having the error.

Comment: Right so this input is labelled by another item on the page, the input doesn't need an ID it is looking for another element on the page with that ID. See if you can find another element with that ID, if not then one needs creating. However as this is an input the easiest way is to just use `<label for="idYouGaveTheInput">label text</label>` and then give your input the same ID as in the `for` attribute. Super robust and super easy. See if you can do it that way, if not then add which library / framework you are using to the question and I will see if I can find the right page for you.

Comment: I think I could fix it. I was missing the same id of the input on the label that was referring. I put the same id and it worked !!! Only for curios, in terms of accessibility, always you have an input you must have it related it to a label field ? Thanks for you help, I'm changing an entire portal to have it done for the 508 compliance and I'm having a lot of small issues haha

Comment: Yes every input should have a label that is correctly associated, it is important for screen reader users otherwise they may get to a form input and it just read "input", which as you can imagine is useless!